# DataFrameのインデックスソート（日付）をかけてもうまくソートできません

Tags: python, sort, dataframe

使用言語: Python
開発環境: Jupyter Notebook

#### 問題の要約

XBRLからcsvファイルに読み込み、抽出した。（結果は、以下のとおり※一部抜粋）
このcsvファイルをDataframeに変換し、四半期毎の売上高を計算した。
この後、インデックスをソートしたが上手くいかなかった。

[image: ![画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import csv
import glob
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

analize_dataframe = pd.read_csv('ファイルパス')
analize_dataframe = analize_dataframe.set_index('value')
q1_data = analize_dataframe.query('会計期間 == "Q1"')["売上高"]
q2_data = analize_dataframe.query('会計期間 == "Q2"')["売上高"]
q3_data = analize_dataframe.query('会計期間 == "Q3"')["売上高"]
fy_data = analize_dataframe.query('会計期間 == "FY"')["売上高"]

def EditQ2Data():
    if len(q1_data) == len(q2_data) :
        edit_q2_data = q2_data - q1_data.values

    elif len(q1_data) > len(q2_data) :
        del_data = list(range(len(q1_data) - len(q2_data) ))
        del_q1_data = q1_data.drop(q1_data.index[del_data])
        edit_q2_data = q2_data - del_q1_data.values
    else:
        print("なんか間違えてない？")
    return edit_q2_data

def EditQ3Data():
    if len(q2_data) == len(q3_data) :
        edit_q3_data = q3_data - q2_data.values

    elif len(q2_data) > len(q3_data) :
        del_data = list(range(len(q2_data) - len(q3_data) ))
        del_q2_data = q2_data.drop(q2_data.index[del_data])
        edit_q3_data = q3_data - del_q2_data.values
    else:
        print("なんか間違えてない？")
    return edit_q3_data

def EditFYData():
    if len(fy_data) == len(q3_data) :
        edit_fy_data = fy_data - q3_data.values

    elif len(q3_data) > len(fy_data) :
        del_data = len(fy_data) - len(q3_data)
        del_q3_data = q3_data.drop(q3_data.index[del_data])
        edit_fy_data = fy_data - del_q3_data.values
    else:
        print("なんか間違えてない？")
    return edit_fy_data

data = pd.concat([q1_data, EditQ2Data(), EditQ3Data(), EditFYData()])
```

#### 試したこと

**入力:**

```
data.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

**出力:** ※一部抜粋

下記画像のようにYYYY/12/31がYYYY/3/31よりも前にきている。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 目標

下記画像のようにYYYY/3/31～YYYY/12/31となるようにしたい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: indexは日付型になっていますか？

Comment: `analize_dataframe = pd.read_csv('ファイルパス', parse_dates=['value'])`としましょう。

Comment: @merino
indexはｓｔｒ型でした。

Comment: @metropolis
問題解決いたしました！ありがとうございます。